# Testing, incoming text message on android emulator

Tags: android, testing, automation

Is it possible to send a text message to an emulator using an automated service?

For example,
We have a system that will send an automated text message to an input phone number.
How do I supply a number to this system that will send the text to my emulator? is this at all possible or should I use a real device? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to test the behaviour of an app when an SMS is received, you can simulate an SMS on an active emulator by connecting to his console port (see the [emulator documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#sms)):

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

and then issuing the command

```
sms send <senderPhoneNumber> <textmessage>
```

where `<senderPhoneNumber>` contains an arbitrary numeric string.

The console forwards the SMS message to the Android framework, which passes it through to an application that handles that message type.

The process can be easily automated. Although using this solution you won't be testing the actual GSM network, but only the behavior of your app when an SMS is received.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however it does not solve the question. You see I am interested in testing the functionality of the automated system, so using the console to send the text kind of defeats the purpose. However I will still give you an up-vote :)

Comment: Ops, I didn't get that. In any case it seems from [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/top-10-sites-receive-sms-online-without-phone/)  that Twilio gives you a private phone number ( I don't know in which state) to receive SMS with their free account. Then you can retrieve the results using their [rest API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message). Hope that helps.